# Please tell me how to resolve the Mongodb connection error

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

(base) ashton@wookui-MacBookPro etc % mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: XXX
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.5.4
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Also, you can see that the studio 3t error also occurs.
I couldn't soloved this problems

[image: 1]

Comment: How are you running mongo ?

Comment: share full error detail (copy paste that 'details' section).

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB?